# read value from method in a python class in c# using ironpython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I want to read the area method from this python class in c#

Does anybody know what I have to do next to achieve this:

Python class:
class Shape(object):

```
def __init__(self,x, y):

     self.x = x
     self.y = y

def area(self):
    return self.x * self.y
```

C# code:

```
        ScriptEngine engine1 = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptSource source1 = engine1.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:\\C#Projects\\ExcelAddIn\\ExcelAddIn\\Shape.py");
        ScriptScope scope1 = engine1.CreateScope();
        source1.Execute(scope1);

        dynamic class_object1 = scope1.GetVariable("Shape");
        dynamic class_instance1 = class_object1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `CreateInstance` method for this (available here: https://github.com/jdhardy/ironpython/blob/master/Runtime/Microsoft.Scripting/Hosting/ObjectOperations.cs).

```
ScriptEngine engine1 = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source1 = engine1.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:\\C#Projects\\ExcelAddIn\\ExcelAddIn\\Shape.py");
ScriptScope scope1 = engine1.CreateScope();
source1.Execute(scope1);

var class_object1 = scope1.GetVariable("Shape");
var class_instance1 = engine1.Operations.CreateInstance(class_object1, 1, 1); // This should create a shape with x = 1 and y = 1
```

Comment: But how can i thereafter read out the value of the 'area' method?

Comment: `class_instance1.area()`